# Frames drop when it comes to the last image - Android FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using the code `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 0.2 -pattern_type sequence -framerate 25 -i /Source_Folder/Temp/a%d.jpg Dest_Folder/name.mp4;`
 
When I execute it for a number of images, I always lose frames in the last image. Ex: If every image comes up for 3 seconds each, the last one just half a second or so short. What should I change in the above command?

Comment: This question will be better answered at http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg; StackOverflow is about programming, see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.